# Transitioning sorting what is displayed on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking for a way to do [something like this](http://www.tienvooracht.nl/themes/?theme=vertue).

Where when you click on  a section it nicely transitions them.

Would it be a Jquery plug in or done with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with both jQuery and CSS, however the CSS support is a little worse than the jQuery-centric solution.

Try something like this for use with jQuery...

```
$('outerdiv').click(function() {
  // `this` being the html element clicked on
  $(this).fadeOut(function() {  //After fadeOut completes,

    $('.page-to-show').fadeIn();  //Fade in target page

  });
});
```

Let me know if you need more advice on how to get this set up.

Comment: Thanks! Now by the looks of it, it would simply fadeOut the parts I don't want, and fadeIn the new ones, and there would be white space left. How would I get the new ones to overlap the space from the ones that have just been faded out?

Comment: I'll update my code a bit.  You can add callbacks to those animations, so that they will happen after the other has been completed.  As far as occupying the same space, you'll have to style your page so that the pages look correct after transitioning.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something along the lines of this plug-in: [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)

Answer (score -1):

try this one. 
Note:.cont stands for the name of the div or the body that u want to fade or something

```
.cont{
animation: transitionIn 2s;
}
@keyframes transitionIn{
from{
opacity: 0;
transform: rotateX(-10deg);
}
to{
opacity: 1;
transform: rotateX(0);
}
}
```